# Is there a good way to check for common substrings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, comparison, substring

I wish to find of a group of words from an input file share common substrings with other words.

So a possible word from the input file would be: "area " 
And a string it would be compared to is "-are--d"

Is there a good way to compare and verify that both strings contain the "are" substring?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.

Here's the code you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{  
  std::string txt="-are--d";

  std::tr1::regex rx("are");
  bool matchFound = regex_search(txt.begin(), txt.end(), rx);
  if(matchFound)
  {
    std::cout << "match found!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions have been in the standard library since C++11. See: [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). In fact, they've been a TR1 library extension since 2007.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's great. I'll update the answer. You kids have it so easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the whole string use `regex_match`. If you want to match a substring use `regex_search`. In g++ 4.8.1 you need to use boost libraries since regex c++11 is not implemented. In g++ 4.8.1 you can compile the code using: `g++ regex_boost.cpp -o regex_boost -lboost_regex`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
//#include <regex>     // it is not implemented in g++ 4.8.1

using boost::regex;
using boost::regex_match;
using boost::regex_search;
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string fnames[] = {"fileone.txt", "data.txt", "pp.txt", "foo.out"};

   regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");

   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
      cout << fnames[i] << ":" << regex_match(fnames[i],txt_regex) << '\n';

   string txt="-are-arde-dsarefdd";

   regex rx("are");

   // not matching because it should match the whole string
   cout << txt << ":" << regex_match(txt, rx) << endl;
   // matching substrings ("are" is matched)
   cout << txt << ":" <<  regex_search(txt, rx) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This program gives result:

```
$ ./regex_boost 
fileone.txt:1
data.txt:1
pp.txt:1
foo.out:0
-are-arde-dsarefdd:0
-are-arde-dsarefdd:1
```